# Time Complexity Nested Loop Inner Loop + Outer Loop

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

Can anyone explain what the time complexity is for this algorithm?

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j += i) {   // note: not j++
        printf("Iteration %d : %d\n", i, j);   
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks exactly like O(n^2) to me

Comment: Is it (n)*(n+1)? So it's time complexity is O(n^2)?

Comment: Wait: I didn't see the `j += i` in the inner loop; that changes it.  Now I don't know :-)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The inner loop runs n times, then n/2, then n/3, etc.  Is that still n^2?

Comment: No, it is about O(n^1.06).

Comment: And no, n is _not_ the _length_ of the input! @Ry

Comment: What formula to produce that value? @Ctx

Comment: @DickyGeraldi None, you can easily determine the value empirically if you do not suspect significant discontinuities (which is not to assume here)

Comment: @Ctx I don't understand how it works. Maybe can you explain how it works if value of N is 3 or 4?

Comment: @Ctx Here's the count for a few values of n:  n=1000,count=8053;
n=10000,count=103643;
n=100000,count=1266714;
n=1000000,count=14969985;
n=10000000,count=172725300;
n=100000000,count=1957511487;

Comment: @Ctx At n=1000, count is ~n^1.30.  At n=100000000, count is ~n^1.16.  Where are you getting 1.06 from?

Comment: @dbush You are doing it wrong; you have to find the value x where 14969985*10^x = 172725300

Comment: @dbush argh you're correct. 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ... 1/n is a harmonic series that does not converge but the sum is `O(lg n)`

Comment: @ctx sure for "small" values of n

Comment: I've posted a rigorous answer to the question. The number of `printf` operations as a function of `n` is `O(n lg n)`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Ok, ok, I'll vote that up... But nonetheless, O(n logn) is a subset of O(n^1.06), so that's correct, too ;)

Comment: @ctx true dat, let me edit some more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `printf` in the inner loop is called *exactly* `ceil(n) + ceil(n/2) + ceil(n/3) + ... ceil(n/n)` times. To get rid of `ceil`, we know that `ceil(y/n)` is bounded above by `y/n + 1`, so we know that the number of executions is `>= n + n/2 + n/3 ... n/n` but is `< n + 1 + n/2 + 1 + n/3 + 1 + n/4 + 1... + n/n + 1`. The former can be factored to `n(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ... 1/n)` and the latter can be refactored into to `n(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ... 1/n) + n`.

The latter factor is of the first addend to infinity is the [the harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), which diverges. The sum of the first `k` terms from the Wikipedia page is known to be bounded:

[image: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/c92abcc9592300b3eca1aac9748346649ba86af9]

which means that `1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ... 1/n` is `Ө(ln n) = Ө(log n)`; we can give strict bounds for the number of times that  `printf` is called (`c(n)`: `n log n <= c(n) < n log n + 2n`. Since `n log n` grows faster than `2n`, we can keep only the former and notice that both bounds belong to *`Ө(n log n)`* and hence *`c(n)`* belongs to *`Ө(n log n)`* as well (`Ө(F)` means that the function is both `Ω(F)` and `O(F)`).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to analyze the complexity is to investigate how many more iterations are added if you double `n`.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 2*n; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= 2*n; j += i) {   // note: not j++
        printf("Iteration %d : %d\n", i, j);   
    }
}
```

This can be broken up into two loops:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= 2*n; j += i) {   // note: not j++
        printf("Iteration %d : %d\n", i, j);   
    }
}

for (i = n+1; i <= 2*n; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= 2*n; j += i) {   // note: not j++
        printf("Iteration %d : %d\n", i, j);   
    }
}
```

In the first loop, it looks like the original loop, but the inner loop size has doubled. So, the first loop runs twice as long as the original algorithm.

For the second loop, the runtime is O(n), since the inner loop does 2 iterations for each value of `i` (excluding the last value of `i`, for which there is 1 iteration).

So, if *T(n)* is the runtime of your original algorithm, then

> *T(2n) = 2×T(n) + C×n*

Which is equivalent to

> *T(n) = 2×T(n/2) + C×n/2*

Which is recognizable as the typical binary divide and conquer complexity of *O(n lg n)*.