# When is the sum of series 1+1/2+1/3+1/4+......+1/n=log n and when is the same sum equal to n, i.e. 1+1/2+1/3+1/4+......+1/n=n

Tags: c, complexity-theory, series

I'm new to understanding asymptotic analysis, while trying to find the big O notation, in a few problems it is given as log n for the same simplification of series and n for another problem.

Here are the questions:

```
int fun(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i= n; i> 0; i/=2)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            count ++;
    return count;
} 

T(n)=O(n)

int fun2(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
        for(j = 1; j <= n; j += i)
            count ++;
    return count;
}

T(n)=O(n log n)
```

I'm really confused. Why are the complexities of these seemingly similar algorithms different?

Comment: Hey Alyna, 
1. I am not able to see how you are relating the series with the example you gave.

Comment: The series in the first case is not 1/n + 1/(n-1) + .......1/2 + 1, rather it is n + n/2 + n/4 +.....

Comment: Now understood your problem, both the above series are different.

Comment: the 2nd algorithm is written incorrectly, it should be      `for(j=1;j<=n;j+=i)`

Answer (score 4):

The series formed in both the cases are different
**Time Complexity Analysis**

1. In this case first `i` will be `n` and the loop for `j` will go till `n`, then `i` will be `n/2` and loop will go till `n/2` and so on , So the time complexity will be

   ```
    = n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8.......
   ```

   The result of this sum is [`2n-1`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401937/how-is-nn-2n-4-1-equal-to-2n-1-using-the-formula-for-geometric-series) and hence the time complexity O(n)
2. In this case when `i` is `n`, we will loop for j `n` times, next time `i` will be `2` and we will skip one entry at a time, which means we are iterating `n/2` times, and so on. So the time complexity will be

   ```
    = n + n/2 + n/3 + n/4........
    = n (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 +....)
    = O(nlogn)
   ```

   The sum of 1 + 1/2 + 1/3... is O(logn). For solution [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367037/sum-of-1-1-2-1-3-1-n).

Comment: @TruthSeeker see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59715688/918959) and [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59671393/918959)

Answer (score 3):

For the former, the inner loop runs *approximately* (exactly if `n` is a power of 2)

```
n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... + n/2^log2(n)
```

times. It can be factored into

```
n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ...  + (1/2)^(log2 n))
```

The 2nd factor is called (a partial sum of) [the geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) which *converges*, meaning that as we approach the infinity it will approach a constant. Therefore it is `θ(1)`; when you multiply this by `n` you get `θ(n)`

---

I've made an [analysis of the latter algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59671393/918959) just a couple days ago. The number of iterations for `n` in that algorithm are

```
ceil(n) + ceil(n / 2) + ceil(n/3) + ... + ceil(n/n)
```

It is quite close to [a partial sum the harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) multiplied by `n`:

```
n * (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... 1/n)
```

Unlike the geometric series the harmonic series does not converge, but it diverges as we add more terms. The partial sums of first `n` terms can be bounded above and below by `ln n + C`, hence the time complexity of the entire algorithm is `θ(n log n)`.